# I am having issues when creating a button with onclicklistener for my sensor

Tags: android, android-button, android-sensors

I am trying to create buttons for my accelerometer sensor. The button allows me to start and stop the accelerometer to get the values that I need. However I am coming up with an error of -

```
The method registerListener(SenesorEventListener, Sensor, int) is not applicable 
for the arguments (new View.OnClickListnere(){}, Sensor, int).
```

Does anyone know where I have gone wrong?? I have put the button code where the protected void onResume() method is.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class movement extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

    private float mLastX, mLastY, mLastZ;
    private boolean mInitialized;
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mAccelerometer;
    private final float NOISE = (float) 2.0;
    Button startButton, stopButton; 
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.movement);
        mInitialized = false;
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer , SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
          mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

        }
    });


    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // can be safely ignored for this demo
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        TextView tvX= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.x_axis);
        TextView tvY= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.y_axis);
        TextView tvZ= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.z_axis);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
        float x = event.values[0];
        float y = event.values[1];
        float z = event.values[2];
        if (!mInitialized) {
            mLastX = x;
            mLastY = y;
            mLastZ = z;
            tvX.setText("0.0");
            tvY.setText("0.0");
            tvZ.setText("0.0");
            mInitialized = true;
        } else {
            float deltaX = Math.abs(mLastX - x);
            float deltaY = Math.abs(mLastY - y);
            float deltaZ = Math.abs(mLastZ - z);
            if (deltaX < NOISE) deltaX = (float)0.0;
            if (deltaY < NOISE) deltaY = (float)0.0;
            if (deltaZ < NOISE) deltaZ = (float)0.0;
            mLastX = x;
            mLastY = y;
            mLastZ = z;
            tvX.setText(Float.toString(deltaX));
            tvY.setText(Float.toString(deltaY));
            tvZ.setText(Float.toString(deltaZ));
            iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (deltaX > deltaY) {
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.horizontal);
            } else if (deltaY > deltaX) {
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.vertical);
            } else {
                iv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
mSensorManager.registerListener(movement.this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

instead of

```
mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

inside the setOnClickListener, because you are inside the OnClickListener you need to access the containing class by naming it first

Comment: I have another question, the errors have disappeared, but when I am running the application on my phone there is an error and the process stops? any idea why that it?

Comment: Could you post your logcat output? It might be worth opening another question if it's a different problem

Comment: I have created buttons for my acclerometer, in order for me to gather data however when I run on eclipse or my phone I get an error

Comment: ^^ I posted a new question